# MSBuild create VDPROJ

Tags: msbuild, vdproj

I know that msbuild does not support VDPROJ files, but it maybe built using command line devenv.

I want to build all prjects (C#) using msbuild task and only after that starting specific setup project from my solution. Of course this projects has dependencies to previously created C# projects (otput from proj1, proj2, proj3).

How could I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override AfterCompile (or AfterBuild) task and add Exec command for devenv.exe to compile vdproj files. When you run devenv.exe  /build /project  you will only build the specified project within the specified solution. Only project files that have changed since the last build will be build. Therefore the dependant projects will not be build unless they have been changed.

Comment: What if the project outputs have indeed changed (e.g. code-signed)? Then the call to devenv.exe will trigger a rebuild of the signed components, overwriting the files and undoing the code-signing. Is there a way to explicitly tell devenv.exe not to build the vdproj dependencies?

Comment: You should not touch project output files. Copy your output files into the different location before code signing.